# Merge two sql queries select and count

Tags: sql

Hello I have two sql queries and i would like to merge or combine them

Query1:

```
Select TableA.Name, TableB.Date
from TableA, TableB
where ID = ID_used;
```

Query2:

```
SELECT count(Date)
FROM  (SELECT DISTINCT Date
       FROM TableA, TableB
       group by Date;
```

I tried:

```
  Select TableA.Name, TableB.Date
  from TableA, TableB
  where ID=ID_used inner join (SELECT count(Date)
                               FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Date
                                     FROM TableA, TableB
                                     group by Date)
```

But it gives syntax error in union query.

The result what I need: Name, count result.

Any Idea?

Test datas:

```
    TableA
    ---------------------
    Name            ID
    ---------------------
    John           1001
    Peter          1002

    TableB
    -----------------------
    Date            ID_used
    -----------------------
    2015.05.01.AM   1001
    2015.05.01.AM   1001
    2015.05.01.AM   1002
    2015.05.01.PM   1001
    2015.05.01.PM   1001
    2015.05.01.PM   1002
    2015.05.01.PM   1002
    2015.05.02.PM   1002
```

Results have to be:

```
    John       2
    Peter      3
```

Comment: Can you show some data and expected result? Query #2 produces a CROSS JOIN before doing GROUP BY.

Comment: do you just need the same result for every row in your result(as in how many destinct dates are there in total) ?

Comment: Tip: count ( and count ). The numbers must match!

Comment: I want to count the date for each Name in the column. The counting works well, but only for  a Name. That's why i try to combine.(the final goal is to take the results to list)

Comment: Jeremy C. the goal will be to get each Name /distinct dates (for the ID).. i will edit the question and give some sample datas

Comment: @Zoltan in the result data you provided the result should be 1 for John and 2 for Peter right? John only has 1st of may and Peter has 1st and 2nd of may?

Comment: no because  the checking is for unique data like 2015.05.01.AM and 2015.05.01.PM is 2 like morning training and afternoon training or morning shift afternoon shift.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Then the result is not : John       2,     Peter      3. The result will be only 2, 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This returns the count of distinct dates from tableB for each Name in tableA:

```
Select a.Name, COUNT(DISTINCT b.Date)
from TableA AS a JOIN TableB AS b
ON ID=ID_used
group by a.Name
```

Comment: syntax error missing operator in query expression 'count(distinct b. date)' What can be the problem?

Comment: @Zoltan: MS Access doesn't support DISTINCT in aggregates, try the Jeremy C.'s answer instead

Comment: @Zoltan: What's your Access release?

Comment: @Zoltan: Seems like Access needs the `INNER` keyword :-)

Comment: dnoeth -- Jeremy C's answer with inner join is working but with Name doesn't  because of aggregate. do you have idea how can i get the Name too?

Comment: @Zoltan: If you only want `Name` remove the `id` from both the SELECT and GROUP BY

Comment: then the result will be only the numbers but the Name won't

Comment: This is Zoltan's query, just the `t1.id` removed: `select t1.name, count(t2.mydate) as datecount
FROM TableA t1
INNER JOIN (
SELECT Distinct id_used,mydate
FROM TableB) t2
ON t1.id = t2.id_used
GROUP by t1.name`

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it what you need is something like this:
(Although I am not sure because you didn't add test data and expected results)

<s>Select t1.Name,t2.Date,
           (select count(date)
            from (select distinct date
                  FROM TableA,TableB
                  GROUP BY Date)) as datecount
    from TableA t1
    join TableB t2
    on t1.ID = t2.ID_used</s>

UPDATE: I think this is what you are looking for: [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2e0940/3)

```
select t1.id, t1.name, count(t2.Date)
FROM TableA t1
JOIN (
SELECT Distinct id_used,Date
FROM TableB) t2
ON t1.id = t2.id_used
GROUP by t1.id
```

EDIT: I tried this in ms access 2010:

NOTE: I couldn't use the keyword Date as a column name so changed to mydate

```
select t1.id, t1.name, count(t2.mydate) as datecount
FROM TableA t1,
 (SELECT Distinct id_used,mydate
FROM TableB) t2
WHERE  t1.id = t2.id_used
GROUP by t1.id,t1.name
```

That worked but I don't recommend using joins without the join or on keywords so here is one that is better readable and also works:

```
select t1.id, t1.name, count(t2.mydate) as datecount
FROM TableA t1
INNER JOIN (
SELECT Distinct id_used,mydate
FROM TableB) t2
ON t1.id = t2.id_used
GROUP by t1.id,t1.name
```

Comment: thank you. but the sql test wrote some error in 'From' syntax

Comment: it's probably in the subquery, did you test your subquery before posting it here? did it return data?

Comment: could you maybe set up some test data, I just read your edit and this probably isn't what you need anyways

Comment: your test data makes it clear, my answer is useless and it might actually be simpler than I thought

Comment: 2015.05.01.AM is in string format because -- if the date is smaller than 12 than the data will be 2015.05.01.AM. Between 12-14:00 no entrance. After this time the data will be 2015.05.01.PM than i can handle the entrance easier , i don't need conversion from 2015.05.01. 00-12:00 to 2015.05.01.AM.

Comment: in this query the way your data is saved doesn't really matter, it should still work with strings

Comment: Yes on fiddle it works perfectly. I check why it gives me error in 'from ' syntax. can it caused of access database?

Comment: so your database is a Microsoft Access database? I don't know if you can perform selects on derived tables in access tbh

Comment: The answer that dnoeth gave should work though, it's almost the same as mine except he does the distinct in the final result instead of using a derived table

Comment: Anything i tried worked in access database this is the first which not.

Comment: can you translate the solution, the query to msaccess type ?

Comment: look at the answer by dnoeth, I think that one should work for msaccess, sadly there is no fiddle for access and also I don't have access on my machine so can't test anything locally either

Comment: MS Access doesn't support DISTINCT in aggregates :-( But AFAIK supports Derived Tables, so your answer should work :-)

Comment: I just found how to do it in msaccess, appearantly access doesn't like the JOIN operator

Comment: @Zoltan I think one of the last 2 should do it

Comment: Thank you for All to help! :)

Answer (score -1):

Use tablename before the column name

```
Select TableA.Name,TableB.Date from TableA, TableB where ID=ID_used;
```

Comment: How this will solve original problem? Not talking even about using old-style join, not using aliases in where condition and other problems.

Comment: Am posted my suggestion on before his question edited. Now my answer was irrelevant because question was changed..

Comment: yes he had right my question was wrong at the first time